# Unable to change owner on a mapped drive directory

Tags: rsync, amazon-ec2, chown, mapped-drive

I am using a script to copy files from amazon instances to a network drive using rsync. After the file copy I am trying to change the owner of these transferred files but am not able to. What is the correct method to change the ownership of files on network folders?
I tried something like

```
chown root:root /mapped/location/
```

I get a permission denied exception. How can I achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: are you root? do you need "sudo chown..."?

Comment: HI, Ya I need sudo chown